# OpenVZ, cannot change password

Tags: linux, passwords, vps, openvz

I'm trying to change password of VPS throught this command:

`vzctl set 180 --userpasswd root:test123 --save`

and it giving me this error: `No changes in CT configuration, not saving`

Using OpenVZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `--save`.

`vzctl set 180 --userpasswd root:test123` should be OK.

To learn more, see [Setting_root_Password_for_Container](http://openvz.org/User_Guide/Operations_on_Containers#Setting_root_Password_for_Container)